# Are the reserved words case sensitive in PHP?

Tags: php, case-sensitive, reserved-words

Are the reserved words in PHP (`final`, `public`, `function`, etc) case-sensitive?

Would it be valid to write:

```
Final Public Function
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out ??

Comment: Why did this need a question? Why not just try it and see if you get an error?!

Comment: @MateiMihai, no, they are not! Keywords are case-insensitive!

Comment: The closure of this question baffles me. "Not constructive"? "Likely to solicit extended discussion"? Not amenable to "facts" or "references"? What a load of tripe. The question is entirely well-defined, with either a "yes" or "no" answer, which should reference either the language reference or the reference implementation.

Comment: @jameshfisher I completely agree. I have voted to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had a problem with case-sensitivity as it relates to reserved words. Sometimes I capitalize them, sometimes I don't. Take a look at this list for examples of usage:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php